# elasticsearch 7 crashing with 127 error - why?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having a problem with Elasticsearch 7. I am running Elasticsearch, Kibana and application on linux server with 64GB RAM. For unknow reason, application is hanging after few hours of working because elasticsearch service is going down with 127 error

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-10-18 06:34:11 CEST;
     Docs: Elasticsearch Platform — Find real-time answers at scale 
  Process: 11831 ExecStart=/opt/elastic/elasticsearch-7.17.5/bin/elasticsearch -p /opt/elastic/elasticsearch-7.17.5/elasticsearch.pid (code=exited, status=127)
Main PID: 11831 (code=exited, status=127)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
```

In elastic I can see such an error:

```
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.898s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.900s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "elasticsearch[opdm-node][[.kibana_task_manager_7.17.5_001][0]: Lucene Merge Thread #981]"
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.898s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.903s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.900s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "elasticsearch[onode][[.kibana_task_manager_7.17.5_001][0]: Lucene Merge Thread #981]"
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.904s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "elasticsearch[node][refresh][T#9]"
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.903s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [23182.904s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "elasticsearch[node][refresh][T#9]"
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: [2023-10-17T06:34:11,076][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node] fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[node][refresh][T#8]], exiting
Oct 18 06:34:11 elasticsearch[11831]: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reache
```

How to find a reason of this issue?

I tried do analyze elastic configuraton but didn't find any suspicious

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the issue is on the last error line:

> OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reache

You probably need to increase your heap size a little bit until it stops crashing. In 7.17, you can change the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` settings in the `jvm.options` file

Comment: Unfortunately, still the problem exist. 

I set:
- LimitNOFILE=131070
- LimitNPROC=8192
- JVM options: -Xms8g and -Xmx8g but still there is an error "unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached" Where to find a root cause?